# URLSearchParams with multiple values

Tags: javascript

I have multiples URLSearchParams created from object mainly because it's lighter to write and to read but for some of them, I need multiple values for a "variable" like this : `foo=bar&foo=baz`.
For now I do it with `.append` but it's heavy to read having multiple lines pretty identical.
Is there a way to do it from the constructor, with an object ?

```js
let params;

// Currently used (and working) code
params = new URLSearchParams()
params.append("foo", "bar");
params.append("foo", "baz");

console.log(params.toString()); //Wanted result but heavy to read with more values

// Wanted code (but not the wanted result for now)

params = new URLSearchParams({
    "foo": ["bar", "baz"]
});

console.log(params.toString());

params = new URLSearchParams({
    "foo": "bar",
    "foo": "baz"
});

console.log(params.toString());
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) can takes an `init` value as argument for its constructor containing the following:

> One of:
>
> - A string, which will be parsed from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. A leading `'?'` character
>   is ignored.
> - A literal sequence of name-value string pairs, or any object — such as a `FormData` object — with an iterator that produces a sequence of
>   string pairs. Note that `File` entries will be serialized as `[object File]` rather than as their filename (as they would in an
>   `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form).
> - A record of string keys and string values.

In your case the second one seems to work the best and can be done like this:

```js
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams([['foo', 'bar'],['foo', 'baz'],['foo', 'qux']])

console.log(searchParams.toString())
```

---

If you want to deal with objects, you can create your own structure and use a function to create the wanted data

For example :

```js
const params = [
  {name: "foo", values: ["bar", "baz", "qux"]},
  {name: "bar", values: ["foo", "foo2", "foo3"]},
]

const initParams = (params) => params.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const arr = curr.values.map(x => [curr.name, x])
  return acc.concat(arr)
}, [])

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(initParams(params))

console.log(searchParams.toString())
```

Answer (score 3):

I would introduce a function to build the thing you need (`URLSearchParams`) from the structure you want (an object containing strings or arrays of strings), pushing the "heavy" details down below an interface you own. A simple implementation would just use `.append` as appropriate:

```js
// For TypeScript (e.g. Angular) users:
// function createSearchParams(params: { [key: string]: string | string[] }): URLSearchParams {
function createSearchParams(params) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  Object.entries(params).forEach(([key, values]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(values)) {
      values.forEach((value) => {
        searchParams.append(key, value);
      });
    } else {
      searchParams.append(key, values);
    }
  });
  return searchParams;
}

console.log(createSearchParams({
  foo: ["bar", "baz"],
  hello: "world",
}).toString());
```

This provides an *abstraction*, so if you decide you'd rather use the `init` approach under the hood, you can do so, e.g.:

```js
function createSearchParams(params) {
  return new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(params).flatMap(([key, values]) => Array.isArray(values) ? values.map((value) => [key, value]) : [[key, values]]));

}

console.log(createSearchParams({
  foo: ["bar", "baz"],
  hello: "world",
}).toString());
```

All of your tests will continue to pass, you don't have to change the consuming code. This is much neater than defining a function to convert the structure you want to the thing *`URLSearchParams` needs*, as shown in [RenaudC5's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72571272/3001761).

Answer (score 1):

First process your data with the parseParam function

```
function parseParam(oldParams, newParams = {}, field = '') {
    for (const key in oldParams) {
        if (oldParams[key] !== null) {
            let field3 = field.length > 0 ? field + '[' + key + ']' : key ;
            switch (typeof oldParams[key]) {
                case 'object':         
                    let object = parseParam(oldParams[key], newParams, field3);
                    newParams = Object.assign(newParams, object);  
                    break;
                case 'string':
                case 'number':                        
                    newParams[field3] = oldParams[key];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return newParams;
}

let query = {
    foo: ['bar', 'baz'],
    status: 3,
    products: {
        door: [4, 8],
        tile: 'not'
    }
};

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(parseParam(query));
console.log(urlParams.toString());
// foo[0]=bar&foo[1]=baz&status=3&products[door][0]=4&products[door][1]=8&products[tile]=not
```

Comment: Code-only answers should be updated to explain how the code resolves the question, further guidance can be found in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log('' + new URLSearchParams(['bar', 'baz', 'qux'].map(v=>['foo', v])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple params like this

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams({a:1,b:2,c:3});
console.log(params.toString());
```

Or you can feed a single string with `&` to the constructor like this `new URLSearchParams("a=1&b=2&c=3")`

---

When you apply these params to an URL-object you could overwrite all params with `url.search =`. But if the url already has a param, it's better to not overwrite it and instead loop through your new UrlSearchParams object and add each param separately with `url.searchParams.append`

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams("a=1&b=2&c=3");
console.log(params);

//You could apply them all to an url
const url = new URL("https://example.com");
url.search = params.toString();
console.log(url.toString())

//But if your url already contains a param, you gotta append new params separately
const url2 = new URL("https://example.com?x=1");
params.forEach((value, key) => { url2.searchParams.append(key, value); });
console.log(url2.toString())
```